# How to create a text file in the directory my application is installed with INNO SETUP?

Tags: winforms, installation, inno-setup

How can I create a file in the directory in which my application is installed?

I've tried the following, and it doesn't work. Basically I need to be able to create the file in C:\Program Files\MyAppName\ on Windows XP or C:\Program Files(x86)\MyAppName on Windows Vista and newer.

```
SaveStringToFile("{pf}\{#MyAppName}\Registration.txt", Serial, False);
```

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is very helpfull...

Comment: try this string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to use the special constant {app}, in case the user chooses a different directory to install it in.

```
SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\Registration.txt'), Serial, False);
```

To save the file in the Application Data directory (shared by all users), use the constant `{commonappdata}` instead of `{app}`.

Note that `{app}` points to "C:\Program Files\My Application\" (or wherever the user chose to install the application and depending on the OS).  `{commonappdata}`, on the other hand, points to the *root* of the Application Data directory, so it'd be good idea in this case to add a directory for your app, (or company and app):

For example:

```
SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\Foobar Corporation\Our Application\Registration.txt'), Serial, False);
```

Comment: How can I write the file to Application data folder instead?

Comment: Here is what I get: Internal error: an attempt was made to expand the "app" constant before it was initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is a permissions issue you should use `Environment.SpecialFolders.ApplicationData` instead. It has an added benefit of allowing you to keep your file if application is uninstalled which can be very useful...

Comment: I know how to do it in .NET...I need to know how to do it using the INNO Setup.

Answer (score -1):

try this string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

Comment: That doesn;t apply to Inno script.